# Java 2D Graphics: can't overlay images

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d

Im trying to get to grips wth java 2d graphics

Ive basically got a JPanel with a backgrounfd image in it like so:

```
public MapFrame(Plotting pl){
    this.pl =pl;
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(984,884));
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    try {
          getFileImage("stars.jpg");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

        }

    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);    
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(new Color(0x756b48));
            g2d.drawLine(0,0,0,100);
}

private void getFileImage(String filePath) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        byte [] b=new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(b);
        in.close();
        bg=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(b);
        MediaTracker mt=new MediaTracker(this);
        mt.addImage(bg,0);
        mt.waitForAll();
     }
```

In paint component I want to overlay small images 12x12 pixels in a loop at various xy points that ill get from some xml.

Cant seem to get an image to overlay over my first one

Im a bit lost here and v rusty

Any help would b gr8

Comment: cheers for typo andriyev

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. The loop you're describing seems to be missing. Do you see the result of the first drawImage call on screen?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(new Color(0x756b48));
    g2d.drawLine(0,0,0,100);

    for(SomeXMLObject o : yourXMLSource) {
        g.drawImage(yourImage, o.x, o.y, null);
    }
}
```

Please specify clearer how your XML is parsed, if you already did that. Then, you'd also need to load the "12x12" image. `SomeXMLObject` is a structure containing `x` and `y` variables, extracted from your XML.

If you call g.drawImage(...) after the background: it will be painted after the background, and thus overlay. Be sure you load a png-24 image, to enable translucency-areas, if you'd want that.

Comment: XmL parsing isnt a problem 

Ive definently got all my filenames and can iterate thru them.

My first image is painted on to a jPanel as a background no problem.

I then want to overlay smaller images at certain points (which I know and have fine from my xml) in front of the background

Comment: Yes, that's what I've understood from your question. Still; nobody can help you if you don't provide enough information.
For instance; what kind of XML parsing do you use, how are the coordinates stored: as an object?
Two other guys have essentially said the same: use <code>g.drawImage(...);</code>, but... you're the programmer! So you have to program something for it to work, right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paint an image at various locations, it is as simple as calling `Graphics.drawImage(Image, int, int, ImageObserver)` multiple times for different coordinates (as shown in the previous answer).

As for loading images, I'd recommend using one of the `ImageIO.read` methods instead of doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use use the [ImageIO library](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) to load your image. If you have an image filename all you need to do to load it is

```
BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.load(new File(filename));
```

That's a little easier then the code you have above.

After that, like other people said you can use the `g.drawImage(bimg,x,y,this);` to actually draw the images.

Answer (score 0):

Oh Dear

Id formatted the filenames of my resources wrong

what a donkey I am

All good advice I think though guys